# authorizing login in shiny io using gspread package

Tags: r, google-docs, google-docs-api

hi I am new to gspread and I would like to put my project in shiny io. However when I do this, I get an error reading from connection using

```
pwd <- getwd()
HTTR_OAUTH <- c(pwd) %>% file.path(".httr-oauth")
HTTR_OAUTH <- HTTR_OAUTH[HTTR_OAUTH %>% file.exists()]

if(length(HTTR_OAUTH) > 0) {
  HTTR_OAUTH <- HTTR_OAUTH[1]
  file.copy(from = HTTR_OAUTH, to = ".httr-oauth", overwrite = TRUE)  
 }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to either make it so in shiny io it asks you for google log in, or if you could provide the user name and password to gspread in the R script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the package has been renamed:

https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

As for integration with Shiny, see the `shinyga` package which recently incorporated support for `googlesheets` and it's method of authentication:

https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/shinyga